# ionic ngCordova geolocation ask for permission

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am using ionic framework to develop an android app. In my app I need to access the current geolocation of the user, I am using ngCordova for this.
Here is my code.

```
var lat, long;
var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};

function getLocation() {
  $ionicLoading.show();
  $cordovaGeolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
      console.log('pos: ', position);
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      long = position.coords.longitude;
    }, function (err) {
      console.log('err here: ',err)
      // error
    });
}

getLocation();
```

I am getting the data and by adding this line

```
<plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
```

I am asking user's permission to access geolocation. 
But the problem is that, if the user has disabled the location initially and opens the app then after giving permission to access location I want to execute getLocation function again.

So how would I know if user has denied or allowed the access ?

Comment: while loading the map you can call Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(). This method got success response means geolocation access permission is given or else show allow the geolocation permission.

Comment: but after the popup to ask for permission is displayed and user selects allow or deny then how would I get to know whether user has allowed or denied

Comment: We can receive success or fail promise

Comment: How? after user selects allow option then how will I execute the function again